# Check FreeBSD version in Makefile

Tags: freebsd, make, gnu-make

I have these lines in my Makefile:

```
PLATFORM     = $(shell uname -r)
OLD_FREEBSD  = 7.3-RELEASE-p2                                                                                                                                            
ifeq ($(OLD_FREEBSD), $(findstring $(OLD_FREEBSD),$(PLATFORM)))
... 
do some stuff
...
else
... 
do some other stuff
...
endif
```

And this works as expected. But I figured out, that some of FreeBSD 7.3 images show output as 7.2-RELEASE-p2 for command "uname -r".
I don't know why it behaves in this way, but I should cover this variant. 
Also, this Makefile (run with gmake) should be valid for newer FreeBSD and CentOS.
So, what's the best way to verify that OS is either 7.3 or 7.2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can compare a string (a word) to several others with [filter](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Text-Functions.html), which returns any that match the word. For example,

```
...
OLDER_FREEBSD  = 7.2-RELEASE-p2
M = $(filter $(PLATFORM),$(OLD_FREEBSD) $(OLDER_FREEBSD))
ifneq ($(M),)
...
```